# How to avoid root appender to appended to sub loggers

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have implement a log4j.xml file having two loggers.
Both EventLogger and ErrorLogger logged in to textfile. Also I create console appender and appended it to the root. My problem is when I use EventLogger or ErrorLogger it both write to the console and to the text file also. I need to avoid that. Can some one please help me.
Following I have showed you the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="ErrorAPPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./log/FIX5SvrError.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="EventAPPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./log/FIX5SvrEvent.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-4r [%t] %-5p %x - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAPP" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>
    <logger name="ErrorLogger">
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="EventLogger">
        <level value="debug"/>
          <appender-ref ref="EventAPPENDER" />
    </logger>
    <root>
        <priority value ="debug" />
         <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAPP" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the loggers whose output you don't want percolating up, you need to set additivity = false.

```
<logger name="ErrorLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" />
</logger>
<logger name="EventLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
      <appender-ref ref="EventAPPENDER" />
</logger>
```

Search for additivity in [the manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for more details.

Comment: It didn't work in above way. But I changed it to <logger name="EventLogger" additivity="false"><level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorAPPENDER" />
    </logger>. Now it working thanks dude for the idea..

Comment: heh heh.  good call...i did put the attributes in the wrong place.  i updated the answer to avoid confusing anyone else.  thanks!